# Using IP address from Facebook's 'Where you're still Logged In' Tab how to track location of iPhone?

Tags: facebook, iphone, ip-addresses

On Facebook, if you log onto your account with your iPhone for instance, under Settings -> Security and Login you'll see the 'Where you're Logged In' and it will say your device i.e., iPhone and where you logged in from(the city) but if you hover over this you'll see a pop-up of an IP address : `XXXX:XXXX:XXX:XXXX:XXXX:XXXX:XXXX:XXXX` in this format. Using this IP address and assuming you're still logged onto Facebook with this device (iPhone) can you track the geo location of this device?

Comment: This question is not related to Facebook.

Comment: @serenesat which forum is most appropriate do you think then?

Comment: That I don't know.